# clear property is not working in ie 7

Tags: html, css

I m using a div in my web site by using float:left and float:right after that is used clear:both, its working fine in all browser except ie7 i have tried a lot of things please tell me a solution to resolve this problem....

css:

```
.clear
{
    clear : both;
    margin : 0px;

}
```

html:

```
<div style="float:left">some text</div>
<div style="float:left">some text</div>
<div class="clear"></div> 
<div style="float:left">some text</div>
<div style="float:left">some text</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a question for [Doctype](http://doctype.com/).

Comment: IE7 seems to have a "bug" in how it handles clear:both. It doesnt work for e.g. label tags if you set that to display:block and have clear:both on those as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding some content to the `div`:

```
 <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

A much better way to do this, though, is [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html).

Comment: Hi 
sorry but it's not working

 <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

Comment: @Mayur strange! Then I don't know what it could be, sorry. Are you sure the CSS is getting loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Add a div in the parent div with no content and clear it using style.For ex.

Comment: You should probably give an example to clarify your answer.